# slow crawl, 6 units, 900 concurrent requests, 10k websites (scrapy cloud)

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

I've been running a plain 'CrawlSpider', that I'm using to gather metadata, on a list of about 10k different domains. The goal is to crawl each website entirely.

Since it's a 'broad crawl', I've given it 6 units to run, and have loaded up CONCURRENT_REQUESTS to 900, while keeping AUTOTHROTTLE_TARGET_CONCURRENCY to 1.

It will run pretty fast the first hour, and then will slowly speed down, after about 3h the speed is at 50 items per minute, which I think is not a lot when we have 900 concurent requests.

I could speed it up to about 250 items/minutes average by increasing AUTOTHROTTLE_TARGET_CONCURRENCY to 50, but some websites would give me a lot of timeout exceptions.

So my question is, Am I doing something wrong? Even when running 'top' on the spider, I can see it running between 60%-90% at the beginning, it's now at 5% max.

Here is my settings.py file

```
SPIDER_MODULES = ['crawl_everything.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'crawl_everything.spiders'

SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware': True,
}

BOT_NAME='bot'
USER_AGENT='bot'
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = True
HTTPCACHE_ENABLED = False
LOG_LEVEL = 'WARNING'
DELTAFETCH_RESET=True

CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 900
CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_IP=20
DOWNLOAD_DELAY=1


DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT = 30

REACTOR_THREADPOOL_MAXSIZE = 100

AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED=False

LOG_LEVEL = 'INFO'
COOKIES_ENABLED = False
RETRY_ENABLED = False
REDIRECT_ENABLED = True
AJAXCRAWL_ENABLED = True
```

Here is my spider

```
class CrawlEverythingSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "crawl_everything"
    allowed_domains = domains
    start_urls = urls
    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(),
         callback='parse_item',
         follow=True
        ),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        item = {}
        item['url'] = response.url
        try:
            item['title'] = response.xpath("//title/text()").extract_first()
        except (AttributeError, NotSupported) as e:
            return

        meta_names = response.xpath("//meta/@name").extract()
        meta_properties = response.xpath("//meta/@property").extract()

        for name in meta_names:
            item[name] = response.xpath("//meta[@name='" + name + "']/@content").extract_first()

        for property in meta_properties:
            item[property] = response.xpath("//meta[@property='" + property + "']/@content").extract_first()

        yield item
```

Answer (score 1):

I should have posted a response earlier.
so when you want to run the same spiders on thousands of websites, your best bet is to divide them into several 'buckets' and attribute each bucket to an instance of the spider (running spider_a, spider_b, spider_c...)
Set up a CONCURENT_PER_DOMAIN to 10, and you can ramp up CONCURRENT_REQUESTS to 1000 with 10 concurent spiders. This is going much much faster than my first solution.